# Can't edit a post in First Posts review because of a pending suggested edit

Tags: support, review

Today I faced a situation on *First Posts* review section where there is one question that I could not edit because it has a suggested edit that is pending review (the "edit" link is opaque and disabled).

In this case, should that post appear on *First Posts* section?

Should I click *No Action Need* instead of skipping because someone else is taking care of it?

Comment: AFAIK if you have already done any action from outside the review page, it enables `I'm Done` button. If this didn't happen to you, it might be a bug IMO.

Comment: Sounds like it's not his edit though.

Comment: @hims056 No, I did not done anything to it.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - Can you post a link of that review?

Comment: @hims056 I'm afraid no, because I skipped it and it's not in my history. That is any other way to find it ?