# Review test bug

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits

Yesterday I also had a [problem with reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190352/cant-edit-a-post-in-first-posts-review-because-of-a-pending-suggested-edit) and today (a couple minutes ago) I had more weird behaviour.

It is about a review test of a nice answer that I choose *No Action Needed* but I failed because the system expected that it be *left as-is or even up-voted* (according to the message). I have left it as-is making no action, indeed.

Here is the [review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2594657) for further information.